# Choosing a committee that's small yet covers all possible views

Tags: algorithms

A community is trying to select a committee of representatives to negotiate with the city council. Each member of the community expresses their political views as a
subinterval of $[0, 100]$. For example, a very left-leaning member may have a view of $(1, 5)$, while a moderately right-leaning member may have a view of $(60, 74)$.
A member will only be satisfied with a committee if the committee contains at least one member whose interval overlaps with their own. (For example, in the extreme case, if there is a very open-minded person with a range of $(0,100)$, that person by themselves would satisfy every member and would be a valid committee all on their own.)

The city council wants to deal with as small a committee as possible. However, they also need to make sure that every member is satisfied with the committee, or the unrest will not go away.

I'm having trouble picking the smallest comitee that satisfies the entire community.

I was thinking of maybe going through the community which is lets say of size $n$ and finding the lower bound and upper bound on the range of views. This could be done in a single sweep taking $O(n)$ time. But, then I'm not sure how to fill in the range to accommodate everyone's views as every member has a different subinterval so I'm not sure which smallest group would work.

Any help would be appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sort the ranges $[R_L,R_H]$ in ascending order of their low end $R_L$. Then make a pass through the members, tracking the members with minimum and maximum high end $R_H$. When you reach a member ($M_2$) whose $R_L$ is greater than the minimum $R_H$ to date, put that member to one side and select for the committee the member $M_1$ with the maximum $R_H$ so far. Restart the process with member $M_2$,  but with the initial min/max $R_H$ values preset to the selected member $M_1$. Continue through all members to fill the committee.